# deisctl list command raises a timeout error what am I doing wrong

Tags: docker, deis

help in "deisctl list" I have just started with deis and am following the  tutorial of using deis in vagrant

am stuck at the part am doing deisctl list am getting this as the output

INFO client.go:291: Failed getting response from http://127.0.0.1:4001/: ssh: rejected: connect failed (Connection refused)
Error: timeout reached

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `DEISCTL_TUNNEL` value is either incorrect or unreachable due to networking/routing/firewall, etc...